# Hibernate, JPA - example manytomany with two tables

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I try to use with many to many collection mapping, I hae two tables :
TASK and TASKRELATED, every task can has many related tasks and every related task can be in many parent tasks. here is my sql diagram:

[image]

Here is my entity :

```
@Entity
public class Task {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long taskId;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "taskRelated", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "relatedTaskId") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "taskId") })
    private Set<Task> relatedTasks = new HashSet<Task>(0);

}
```

Here is my ropository :

```
public interface ITaskRepository extends JpaRepository<Task, Long>, 
    QueryDslPredicateExecutor<Task>{
}
```

This is my code :

```
Task t = repository.findOne(1L);
```

This is my data in mysql:
task table
[image]
taskrelated table
[image]

When I do read of task object, there is en error:

```
    failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: org.Task.relatedTasks, no session or session was closed
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: org.Task.relatedTasks, no session or session was closed
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:383)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationExceptionIfNotConnected(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:375)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet.size(PersistentSet.java:162)
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.sample.service.UsersServiceTest.testTask(UsersServiceTest.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
```

Please help !

in case of `@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)` there is error like this :

```
 illegal access to loading collection
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: illegal access to loading collection
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:366)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet.hashCode(PersistentSet.java:434)
    at org.Task.hashCode(Task.java:36)
    at java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:351)
    at java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:471)
    at java.util.HashSet.add(HashSet.java:217)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:334)
    at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet.endRead(PersistentSet.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.engine.loading.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollection(CollectionLoadContext.java:261)
    at org.hibernate.engine.loading.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.engine.loading.CollectionLoadContext.endLoadingCollections(CollectionLoadContext.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.endCollectionLoad(Loader.java:1005)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:993)
```

Comment: You forget to post UsersServiceTest.testTask(). You know, the place where the exception happens. I can already venture a guess that no JPA transaction is actually started anywhere around that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot initialize the collection, have you tried adding the set without initializing it?:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "taskRelated", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "relatedTaskId") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "taskId") })
private Set<Task> relatedTasks;
```

Answer (score 1):

As the exception says you are trying to access the collection elements - `relatedTasks` after closing the session and Hibernate lazily loads the collection elements by default.

So you need to access the elements within the session or alternatively you can add the fetch type to `EAGER`

```
 @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
```

**Update:**

As per stacktrace for exception - `LazyInitializationException: illegal access to loading collection` it has:

```
at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet.hashCode(PersistentSet.java:434)
at org.nli.seoweb.domain.Task.hashCode(Task.java:36)
```

Based on this I am assuming you have overridden the `hashCode` method in `Task` entity and this method is trying to access the `Set`. As Hibernate provides a wrapper class for the `Set` which is `PersistentSet` in this case, calling `hashCode()` internally has a validation that checks if the `Set` is fully initialized or not and then throw the exception.

So try modifying your `Task.hashCode()` method and make sure you are not using the `Set` in it, and see if it fixes the issue.

You can also refer to [this post](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=962889) for similar exception.

Comment: ok, as mentioned by Gimby add the code which is causing this issue.

Comment: @priliam, also can you add code for `org.nli.seoweb.domain.Task.hashCode()` method, it seems the error has some relation with your hashcode method.